# Change Card Manager AID on JavaCard 3.x

Tags: javacard, globalplatform, jcop

I'm trying to change the card manager AID on a JavaCard 3.x smartcard by using a `STORE DATA` command. The current card manager AID is the factory default of `A0 00 00 01 51 00 00 00`. After authenticating with the card manager, the command I'm sending is:

```
=> 80 E2 80 00 0A 4F 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00
<= 6A 88
```

This command executes successfully on a JavaCard 2.2.x card - has this feature been deprecated on JC 3.x?

Comment: this feature is usually implementation/ vendor dependent. check the manual of your specific java card

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the JavaCard 3 needs the command data in DGI format for this to work:

```
=> 80 E2 80 00 0D 00 70 0A 4F 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00
<= 90 00
```